# Minio dial tcp 127.0.1.1:443: connect: connection refused

Tags: minio

after upgrading via `mc` command i get this error when i try to login to the (kind of new) minio console:

`Post "https://fqdn.org/": dial tcp 127.0.1.1:443: connect: connection refused`

I have a signed and valid SSL Certificate.
Downgrading minio (aka restore Snapshot of VM) solves the problem.

Any ideas?

This is my config:

```
MINIO_SERVER_URL="https://fqdn.org"
MINIO_ACCESS_KEY="key"
MINIO_VOLUMES="/mnt/hdd2/minio/"
MINIO_OPTS="-C /etc/minio --address :9000 --console-address :9001"
MINIO_SECRET_KEY="minio"
```

This is my minio startup log:

```
● minio.service - MinIO
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/minio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-11-11 08:41:14 CET; 4min 50s ago
     Docs: https://docs.min.io
  Process: 3567 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ -z "${MINIO_VOLUMES}" ]; then echo "Variable MINIO_VOLUMES not set in /etc/default/minio"; exit 1; fi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3568 (minio)
    Tasks: 9 (limit: 2351)
   Memory: 101.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/minio.service
           └─3568 /home/minio/minio server -C /etc/minio --address :9000 --console-address :9001 /mnt/hdd2/minio/

Nov 11 08:41:14 pmit-minio-test systemd[1]: Starting MinIO...
Nov 11 08:41:14 pmit-minio-test systemd[1]: Started MinIO.
Nov 11 08:41:17 pmit-minio-test minio[3568]: WARNING: MINIO_ACCESS_KEY and MINIO_SECRET_KEY are deprecated.
Nov 11 08:41:17 pmit-minio-test minio[3568]:          Please use MINIO_ROOT_USER and MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD
Nov 11 08:41:17 pmit-minio-test minio[3568]: API: https://fqdn.org
Nov 11 08:41:17 pmit-minio-test minio[3568]: Console: https://191.164.213.7:9001 https://127.0.0.1:9001
Nov 11 08:41:17 pmit-minio-test minio[3568]: Documentation: https://docs.min.io
```

Answer (score 3):

Please see the answer here:
https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/13639#issuecomment-966244704

I had to change this line:
`MINIO_SERVER_URL="https://fqdn.org:9000"`